# Combining two stacked ImageViews into one long ImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I want a function in Swift that combines two vertically stacked UIImageViews into one large UIImage that maintains the size and arrangement. I have seen some objective C code on this but I haven't learned that language yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide that link where you had seen objC code so here can i get better idea that what actually you wants ?

Comment: I was looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview

Comment: and I tried some of their methods but it gives me a blank image.

Comment: Here is a question very similar to mine in obj-C http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670757/merge-two-imageviews-into-one-and-save-ios-swift

Comment: I also corrected the question, I meant UIImage as the output. I want to be able to send a single image to a printer.